# Serious lag when typing content on tinyMCE editor in IE Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, tinymce, microsoft-edge

I have integrated tinyMCE (4.3.2)version in Asp.net application. When we keep typing in IE versions, the typing content get a serious lag.

In Chrome and Firefox this works very smoothly. This only happens in IE. It is highly noticeable lag in Edge. Any suggestions or workaround to overcome this issue?

Comment: turn-off auto save every keyup event

Comment: Without seeing how you have TinyMCE configured nobody will be able to provide you any real help.  Perhaps you can make a TinyMCE Fiddle or JS Fiddle that shows exactly how you have TinyMCE configured so people can look at how you have things setup?

Answer (score 1):

i solved this issue by forcing IE to  version10 then 
try add this tag 
     `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">`
chau!